# how to get the selected suggestion value in text box

Tags: angularjs

I have a form in that I have to show suggestions for skills text field, I tried it with using ng-repat and list view, but my problem is if the user click on the available suggestions, I need that value in ng-model, I had given anchor tag for each li but it is not working please help me, thanks in advance. Below is the i tried code

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sampleapp = angular.module("myapp", []);
sampleapp.controller("myctrl", function($scope, $http){

$scope.fruits = ['php', 'python', 'perl', 'java', 'javascript', 'ajax', 'servlets', 'html', 'sap', 'sap/abap', 'sap/pico'];

$scope.selectQuasuggestions=function(sid){
    $scope.query = sid;
}
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
ul
{
background-color: #fff;
width: 12%;
padding: 5px;
margin: 1px;
overflow-y: scroll;
border:1px solid brown;
height: auto;
}
li{
  padding-bottm: 5px;
  line-height:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="enter your skills"/>
<div ng-show="query">
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | filter:query"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="selectQuasuggestions($index);" class="ng-binding"> {{quasuggestionss.name}}</a>{{fruit}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `$scope.searchQua`?

Comment: What is this $scope.searchQua[sid] ? There is no reference to searchQua

Comment: may i know what exactly your trying to output

Comment: if i type java in skill text filed some suggestions are showing, if i select java script i need that value in skill text filed

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<select>` tag

```
<div ng-show="query">
  <select ng-model="query">
      <option ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | filter:query" class="ng-binding">{{fruit}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

See the attached [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/04zlnKrc7C6ufudZT4uD?p=preview) for **o/p**
May be this will help you

**OR**
Use **typeahead** property of ui-bootstrap
check the following pluncker link for typeahead example

**[PLUNCKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/xUNR92OxiXBfdtSrH1oL?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for your answer, in your answer we have to click on that options tag to  see suggestions, but i don't want like that

Comment: @nareshkumar use typeahead property of ui-bootstrap so it will come in proper stucture. if you want then I will provide one plunkr example

Comment: please provide the example

Comment: @nareshkumar I have updated my answer please check the pluncker some examples are there